# How many $3$ letter words can be formed from the word "$TESTBOOK$"?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

How many $3$ letter words can be formed from the word "$TESTBOOK$" ?

---

Letters in this word are : $T,E,S,B,O,K$

- Make a $3$ letter word from $6$ distinct => $P(6,3) = 120$ ways
- Now, Make a $3$ letter word from repeating letters => $C(2,1) * C(3,2) * C(5,1) = 30$ ways

Total $3$ letter words = $150$

---

Am I right here or missing any possibility ?

Comment: For the second bullet point: Why not: there are 6 choices for the first letter then 6 choices for the second letter and then 6 choices for the third letter giving $6^3$ choices? It is suspicious that the number of words selected by repetition allowed is les than the correspondig number (with no repetition)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the second formula should be $C(2,1)*C(3,2)*C(5,1) = 30$

Comment: @trueblueanil typo corrected :-)

Comment: @zoli there are two sets of characters which may repeat and they may only repeat once. Hence using $O,O$ or $T,T$ as two of the letters in one of our three letter words leaves few possibilities for the third letter. Not to mention we have many more distinct letters than we have letters that repeat.

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon  Ah so, repeating means only: using twice...

Comment: @zoli: Repeating does *not* mean using only twice. There are only $2$ sets of duplicates, and since the word is to have only $3$ letters, it is not *possible* to repeat more than twice.

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon: OK, got it. Thanks.

Comment: @trueblueanil Had it been " $3$ letter words that can be formed and arranged ", then the second bulleted point should be => $C(2,1)∗C(5,1) * 3!/2!$ . Am I right here ? Same idea for bulleted point $1$ also !

Comment: No, "words ... formed" means permissible permutations of letters, and $C(2,1)*C(3,2)*C(5,1)$ already takes care. (Choose letter that repeats)$\times$ (Choose $2$ places for them)$\times$(Choose another letter and place it in vacant slot), e.g. $TET, TTE, ETT$ are all taken care of.

Comment: @trueblueanil Many thanks :-) That's valuable for me .

Answer (score 1):

Hint -

For second case take repeating letters as group. So we have 2 groups and 4 distinct alphabets.

Pick 1 from group and 1 from 4 distinct letters.